# Generate Table dynamic inside a form

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

I am having a little problem with the form system in Symfony 3.3.

I do want to generate a table of form-fields inside a form, depending on the data the user is selecting inside the form.

For example, I have one field with a daterange, that I want to use for the days beeing displayed on the x-axis. On the y-axis I want to display the data the user has selected from a multiselect, that has 1..3 different categories.

The goal is to generate a table after these fields are selected, that has an integer formtype for each cell, that can be changed by the user.

I am quite new to symfony and this really makes my head hurt.
My question is, what would be the easiest or at least most clever concept to achieve this goal in Symfony 3.3?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Symfony Form Events: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html you might be looking for preSubmit or postSubmit.

You could also look at a data transformer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Finally based on you wanting to render a table, you could probably do this just in twig templates: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html